# Port scanner shows module error, what is this relating to?

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I'm going through the book violent python and using some examples from github to write the code in python 3. All has been going well for the most port but on the port scanner program I'm running into this repeated error module 'socket' has no attribute 'SOCKET_STREAM'. I have tried searching for this but most of the examples I've seen don't relate.

I've tried coding this on windows and Linux although I don't believe it's an OS issue.

```
#!/bin/bash/python 3.7
import argparse
import binascii
import socket
import threading

screen_lock = threading.Semaphore(value=1)


def conn_scan(target_host, target_port):
    conn_skt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCKET_STREAM)
    error = conn_skt.connect_ex(target_host, target_port)
    screen_lock.aquire()
    if not error:
        print("[*] %d tcp open, " % target_port)
    else:
        print("[*] %d tcp closed." % target_port)

    screen_lock.release()
    conn_skt.close()


def ban_scan(target_host, target_port):
    try:
        conn_skt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        conn_skt.connect(target_host, target_port)
        conn_skt.send(b'ViolentPython3\r\n')
        conn_skt.recv(100)
        screen_lock.aquire()
        print("[+] %d/tcp open " % target_port)
    except Exception:
        print("[-] %d/tcp closed " % target_port)
    finally:
        screen_lock.release()
        conn_skt.close()


def initiate_scan(target_host, target_ports):
    try:
        target_IP = socket.gethostbyname(target_host)
    except Exception:
        print("[-] Cannot resolve '%s': Unknown host" % target_host)
        return
    try:
        target_name = socket.gethostbyaddr(target_IP)
        print("\n[+] Scan results for: " + target_name[0])
    except Exception:
        print("\n[+] Scan results for : " + target_IP)

    socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
    for target_port in target_ports:
        print("Scanning port " + target_port)
        t = threading.Thread(target=conn_scan, args=(target_host, int(target_port)))
        t.start()


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-H', '--host', help='specify target host')
    parser.add_argument('-P', '--port', help='specify target ports separated by comma')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    target_host = args.host
    target_ports = str(args.port).split(',')

    if(target_host is None) | (target_ports[0] is None):
        parser.print_help()
        exit(0)
    initiate_scan(target_host, target_ports)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Should show output of the port scan

Comment: Is `/bin/bash/python` really the location of your Python interpreter? Usually `/bin/bash` is an executable, not a directory.

Comment: It's a typo. `socket.SOCKET_STREAM` should be `socket.SOCK_STREAM`

Comment: You did it correctly in `ban_scan`, you couldn't see the difference?

Comment: I actually just spotted that. I'm running into other weird errors but I'll try to resolve those myself.